# Redirect to error page on web method call when session is expired in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, redirect, web-config

Everytime my page loads a base page which is inherited to it checks for session and based on which the it redirects from the base page if its not in session.
But now though my page is not in session and if I try to access element in that page which makes a WCF call it works. which is not suppose to happen.

Is there any way to check if session is expired when it makes WCF call and also redirect to error page from C# itself without having to do from javascript.

Answer (score 1):

You can't redirect within a web method but you can check session and throw an exception:

```
    [WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
    public static void SomeWebMethod()
    {
        if (System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["SomeSessionVar"] == null)
        {
            throw new Exception("ERROR: Session has Expired");
        }
    }
```